# Are ISO 8601 and unix timestamp formats 1:1?

Tags: timestamp, iso8601

Does every ISO 8601 timestamp correspond to exactly one unix timestamp, and vice versa?

Another way to ask: Let `to_unix` be a function that converts an ISO 8601 timestamp into a unix timestamp, and `to_iso` be a function that converts a unix timestamp into an ISO 8601 timestamp. Does there exist a unix timestamp `u` such that `u != to_unix(to_iso(u))` or an ISO 8601 timestamp `i` such that `i != to_iso(to_unix(i))`?

I ask because we have unix timestamps in our database, and want to use ISO 8601 for readability in an API, and I'm wondering if that could ever be a problem.

Comment: Are you considering a "unix timestamp" to be an integer, as in the type `time_t`, or are you considering that it may have a fractional part? Are you interested in being concerned about [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)?

Comment: Our unix timestamps are integers representing number of milliseconds past the epoch. ISO 8601 allows a decimal part, so we can accurately represent those milliseconds. No floating point numbers are involved.

Comment: Leap seconds are worth considering. My understanding is that they mean either that a timestamp will be repeated, or a timestamp will be skipped, neither of which affects representation. Just because timestamp `u` will never be generated (because it's skipped) doesn't necessarily imply that any conversions involving it are lossy.

Comment: @theazureshadow No - leap seconds can be represented in ISO-8601 by "2015-06-30T23:59:60Z" but they are not representable in Unix timestamps. So this is one example of lossy translation. More important: Unix timestamps cannot be defined in an arbitrary high subsecond precision (different in ISO).